# Full screen background not working on ipad

Tags: html, css

Would you know why, on [my website](http://goo.gl/n7S1w) full screen background doesn't work on ipad? Many thanks

I tried this:

```
#presentation {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #afc9ff;
    background: url(../images/bg-24.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; 
    -moz-background-size: 100%; 
    -o-background-size: 100%; 
    background-size: 100%; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;

}
```

and this

```
#activity {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #8aba56;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: url(../images/bg-22.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
#activity {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #8aba56;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: url(../images/bg-22.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that doesn't work (I tried for the "activity" DIV, second menu item). Have updated the link in my post accordingly if you want to have a look. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#presentation {
 background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #AFC9FF;
background-image: url(../images/bg-24.jpg)
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 1300px;
-webkit-background-size: 100%; 
-moz-background-size: 100%; 
-o-background-size: 100%; 

-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
}
```

good luck...

Answer (score 0):

in body add

```
<div id="fixedbg">
</div>
```

next to

and add CSS

```
#fixedbg{
    background:url(../img/sec2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed !important;
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Best of luck....